# How to annotate a decorator that returns a `property`

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to create a decorator that return a `property` of the decorated function, i.e:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


def make_prop(param):
    def wrapper(func) -> 'property(func)':
        return property(func)
    return wrapper


class A:

    @make_prop('foo')
    def a(self) -> str:
        return "hello"


a = A()
assert a.a == "hello"

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a.a)
```

This is what `reveal_type` prints

```
note: Revealed type is "Any"
```

While the code above runs correctly and the type should be `str`

Comment: Can you add `reveal_type` function?

Comment: wym? I have a `reveal_type` there.

Comment: I mean the implementation, because I tried your code and it seems work. When I call `a.a` it returns `hello`. and `type(a.a)` returns `str`.

Comment: I know I want it to be compatible with mypy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with the `property` from Python's builtins, because their type isn't generic (see the [typeshed stubs](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/6011cac0cc34b003ce029ae079306db8b8ee7f5f/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1171-L1188)).

As with most things in a class body, you'll have to understand Python's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to come up with a typing construct that does this properly. To start off, implement your own generic version of `property`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

R = t.TypeVar("R")

class property_(property, t.Generic[R]):
    fget: cx.Callable[[t.Any], R]
    fset: cx.Callable[[t.Any, R], None] | None
    fdel: cx.Callable[[t.Any], None] | None
    if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
        def __new__(
            cls,
            fget: cx.Callable[[t.Any], R],
            fset: cx.Callable[[t.Any, R], None] | None = ...,
            fdel: cx.Callable[[t.Any], None] | None = ...,
        ) -> property_[R]: ...
        @t.overload
        def __get__(self, obj: None, type_: type | None = ...) -> property_[R]: ...
        @t.overload
        def __get__(self, obj: object, type_: type | None = ...) -> R: ...
        def __get__(self, obj: object, type_: type | None = None) -> property_[R] | R: pass
        def __set__(self, obj: t.Any, value: R) -> None: ...
```

Then, your `make_prop` can be simplified to

```py
def make_prop(func: cx.Callable[[t.Any], R]) -> property_[R]:
    return property_(func)
```

Finally,

```py
class A:
    @make_prop
    def a(self) -> str:
        return "hello"


a: A = A()
assert a.a == "hello"

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a.a)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
    reveal_type(A.a)  # mypy: Revealed type is "property_[builtins.str]"
```

Note that `A.a != "hello"`; this is what the first overload `def __get__(self, obj: None, type_: type | None = ...) -> property_[R]: ...` handles.

---

As the question has been edited to set `make_prop` as a decorator factory instead, the minor change to `make_prop` would be

```py
def make_prop(param: t.Any) -> cx.Callable[[cx.Callable[[t.Any], R]], property_[R]]:
    def wrapper(func: cx.Callable[[t.Any], R]) -> property_[R]:
        return property_(func)

    return wrapper


class A:
    @make_prop("foo")
    def a(self) -> str:
        return "hello"
```

```py
a: A = A()
assert a.a == "hello"

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(a.a)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
    reveal_type(A.a)  # mypy: Revealed type is "property_[builtins.str]"
```

Comment: Note: If you're not using `mypy`, this solution may not work. In particular, `pyright` doesn't handle subclassing from `property` very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the returning value of `make_prop` as a wrapper callable that takes a callable that returns a type variable that is the same as what the wrapper callable returns:

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar('T')

def make_prop(param) -> Callable[[Callable[..., T]], T]:
    def wrapper(func):
        return property(func)
    return wrapper
```

Or to type the inner wrapper function as well:

```
def make_prop(param) -> Callable[[Callable[..., T]], T]:
    def wrapper(func: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
        return cast(T, property(func))
    return wrapper
```

Demo:
https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=afcdaafe99dbdc075a3be650d8582252

Comment: Umm, this implementation will cause the static type checker to think that accessing the property from the class is the actual value.

Comment: @dROOOze And that's the whole point of a property, so that accessing a property feels no different from accessing the actual value.

Comment: No, accessing from a class gives a property object. Accessing from the **instance** gives the value.